# In Rally's 'Iteration Status' view, can you export User Stories AND Tasks to a .csv file?

Tags: csv, export, task, rally

In Rally, I see the Tasks underneath the User Stories in the 'Iteration Status' view, but when I go to export to .csv, I only get the User Stories list but not the associated Tasks nested under the story.  Can anyone tell me how I can add that or create that code?

Thank you for your help!

--david

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately the Export to CSV function from the Track/Status screen doesn't support exporting Stories and Tasks together. It's a pretty long-standing feature request:

https://ideas.rallydev.com/ideas/D244

Perhaps add your vote on Rally's ideas site. The Rally Excel add-in, while it doesn't automate the process of exporting Stories together with Tasks, makes the manual 2 step process perhaps a bit easier and more flexible.